# Dell R730 PERC H730p mini performance issue post BIOS Update

Tags: ssd, bios, raid, windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge

I am scratching my head on this issue so it's time to ask the community!

Below is a benchmark after a fresh install of Windows Server 2012

[image: This is pre bios update performance on a RAID 1+0 array w/ 8 x 800 GB SSD's]

This next picture is a benchmark I happened to do AFTER updating my BIOS and controller firmware.

[image: This is post bios update]

- Layout   RAID-10 Size
- List item  2978.50 GB
- Span Depth   1
- Block Size   512 bytes Bus
- Protocol SATA
- Media Type   SSD
- Read Policy  Read Ahead
- Write Policy Write Through
- Stripe Size  64K
- Disk Cache Policy Default

I have tried all possible combinations of Read cache policy, write policy and disk cache with little to no change. I believe the cache on the controller is roughly equal to the SSD's performance by itself.

This is a brand new machine fresh out of the factory and an UPDATE made this happen. Dual 3Ghz Xeon's and 192GB RAM

Any ideas what might have changed?

EDIT: I also re-installed the old BIOS and still am not getting the previously mentioned performance.

Answer (score 1):

The H730p has 2GB cache. To test the speed you will have to use file with size bigger than 2 GB. If the size is less like in your case  ( just 1 GB ) the results will be very inconsistent. Actually you are testing the controller cache speed.

Data Consulting Group  - tech support

Comment: I will be sure to do that! Makes sense.